# UITableView pads touch area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode7-beta2

I follow [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html) to make a simple app using table (as in the below image).

The red area height is 8 point.
Why is touching the red area does not select first row ("Buy milk")?

Is it expected or is it a bug? How to fix?

[image]

Comment: Any reason for down voting?

Answer (score 0):

It is not TableView Cell's area, that is why it is not detecting it. You can test it by assigning a background color to the cell of tableview, and then see what is the area of tableview

Comment: I have tried what you suggest. Change background colour of cell. The red area colour is same as cell's background colour and still the touch cannot be detected.

Comment: Probably, "To-Do List" header comes over it, so it does not detect the touch

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? If something comes over the cell, should the red area have different colour than cell's colour? But in this case, it has the same colour.

Comment: Can you give color to your cells and show me the image?

Answer (score 0):

You may return for each cell of UITableView header section. 
You can show the implementation of this method?

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: There is no implementation for that delegate.